# Rcpp function that returns Matrix or DataFrame depending upon input

Tags: r, rcpp

I have two functions in Rcpp:

```
//[[Rcpp::export]]
DataFrame func1(DataFrame& x) {
  ...
}

//[[Rcpp::export]]
NumericVector func2(NumericMatrix& x) {
  ...
}
```

How can I write a common function

```
SEXP func(SEXP& x) {
  ...
}
```

that uses the `func1` if the input is a `DataFrame` and `func2` if the input is a `Matrix`.

I tried to look up examples on the net, such as the one given here : http://gallery.rcpp.org/articles/fast-factor-generation/ but I couldn't get it to work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need `is<>`, i.e. Something like this:

```
if( is<DataFrame>(x) ){
   return func1(x) ; 
} else {
   return func2(x) ;
}
```

However for this to work, you need to use a reference to const, i.e. a `const DataFrame&` or create the `DataFrame` before you feed `func1`. Something like this:

```
if( is<DataFrame>(x) ){
    DataFrame df(x) ;
    return func1(df) ; 
} else {
    NumericMatrix m(x) ;
    return func2(m) ;
}
```

Comment: would it be possible for you to give a code snippet which uses `const DataFrame&` as I want to avoid passing the whole `DataFrame`

Comment: Passing by value or by reference is the same for Rcpp objects. This is all over the documentation.

Comment: thanks. where do I incorporate `const DataFrame` ? In  the `func1`?

Comment: `DataFrame func1(const DataFrame& x){ ... }`